# separate two different companies by URL

Tags: php

In my php coding, by means of URL, it identifies the company.
For example, if company name is comp1 then it's url will be `www.comp1.com` and for comp2 `www.comp2.com`

It will automatically put `company_id` in session by URL.

**Problem**

Do I need to copy entire code of comp1 to comp2 to establish new company? Is there any way to do this kind of thing? I can not redirect URL. Because it will change URL after redirecting.
Database will be same for every companies.

Let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, point both domains at the same location, then do some logic with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to load the correct data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point both domains at the same IP. You can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to determine which URL was requested and dole out data as needed.

See [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) for more details

Comment: So, basically I need to redirect URL and then by `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`, i need to identify. right?

Comment: 1 more thing, is there any performance issue in redirecting URL?

Comment: You don't need to redirect. Just set your domain records to point at the same server.

Comment: ok.. I got it. I am using windows azure. I am pointing github repository for both URLs. It's working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, follow these steps

1. Change the DNS for both domains to point to the same IP (server)
2. Configure your Virtual hosts for both domains to point to the same directory on the server. So you will be using same files for both domains.
3. Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in your code to determine which URL it is. Redirecting will not help you here